# How to make initials icon like in Gmail?

Tags: android, xml, view

What I want to do:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

I want to make a circular icon with initials in it. In my scenario initials can have one or two letters. Like you can see my solution work fine for two letters but not to one. How can I solve this for both cases?

There is my code from the XML file:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_rounded_blue_button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center" 
    local:MvxBind="Text Initials"/>
```

And there is shape_rounded_blue_button:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
<corners android:radius="30dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `drawable` resource file under **res>drawable** and save it as `bg_circle.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"> 
        <solid android:color="#424242"/> 
        <size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

Now make `icon_container` in your `layout.xml` file as:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/icon_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_width_height"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_circle" /> 
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/icon_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/icon_text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

For complete code implementation visit [Implementing  Gmail like icon with text and random colors](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/02/android-creating-gmail-like-inbox-using-recyclerview/)

Comment: Instead of having two views (`TextView` + `ImageView`) you can just have one `TextView` and add the drawable shape as `background` to the textview.

Answer (score 6):

As I wanted to implement the same thing, I made some research on GitHub and found this library:
https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable

It does exactly what you want and has some neat features as auto-coloring. You can use it with an `ImageView` and create a drawable, e.g. like this:

```
val drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
        .beginConfig()
        .width(bubbleSize)
        .height(bubbleSize)
        .endConfig()
        .buildRound("FH", MATERIAL.getColor("FH"))
theImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable)
```

And that looks like this: 
[image: Round Image View]

Your text will automatically be centered within the bubble, so it's no problem to have one or two characters.

Comment: not worthy for me it i pass size it will not increae bubble size

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a circle shape.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="@color/base30"/>
```

For better effects(shadow and appearance) you can use [TextDrawable](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable).